# Сложный запрос sql в 2 и более БД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Я новичок в программировании, мне нужно написать запрос в MySQL базу, у меня есть список нужных таблиц (который я получил запросом из схемы), из которых нужно получить определённые данные. Как это осуществить с помощью курсора или иным способом? Данный код выдаёт почему-то ошибку 1064 о наличии синтаксической ошибки. В чём может быть ошибка? Работаю в phpmyadmin.
P.S. Да, запрос не полный и точно есть ошибки, я это понимаю.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()

BEGIN

DECLARE tb1 CHAR(255);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT c.TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 

WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'id' c;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET tb1 = "EMPTY";

OPEN cur;

FETCH cur INTO list1;

CLOSE cur; 
END;`
```

Comment: В чем именно у вас проблема? не понимаете описание ошибки?

Comment: С ошибкой я разобрался, проблема с синтаксисом, но почему вылезает ошибка - я не понимаю, вроде правильно писал. Причём ошибка указывает на строчку с BEGIN. Но основная проблема в самом запросе, не пойму, правильно ли я пишу запрос и каким ещё способом, помимо курсора, можно заполучить нужные мне данные. Я получил список таблиц первой базы из information_schema, теперь мне нужен запрос в первую базу, чтобы пройтись по списку таблиц и вытащить из них нужные данные.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER --NJHlksa8yfsp87_^*_--
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE tb1 CHAR(255);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'id' ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET tb1 = "EMPTY";
  OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur INTO list1;
  CLOSE cur; 
END--NJHlksa8yfsp87_^*_--
```

Со следующей ошибкой надеюсь сами справитесь?

```
/* Ошибка SQL (1327): Undeclared variable: list1 */
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)